# Execute more than 138 parallel tasks using asynctask in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a requirement that i need to execute parallel async tasks 255 times i.e more than 138 times(which is maximum async tasks I am allowed to perform).My code is below-

```
   try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            Log.e(TAG," i==="+i);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                    new ClientTask(Client.this,new MyCallback()).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "10.0.0." + i);
                else
                    new ClientTask(Client.this,new MyCallback()).execute("10.0.0." + i);
            }

    }catch (RuntimeException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Right now this code is executing exactly 138 times and checking for connections to ip from 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.138 but i want this to check up until 10.0.0.255. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On finish of one async task start another

Comment: In the end it won't be parallel anyway, unless you run it on a 255-core processor.

Comment: Create your own executor with a bigger thread pool and pass it to "executeOnExecutor". However if the task is not supposed to return a result or publish updates on the main thread, you should probably not use an AsyncTask. And 255 threads at once is a lot for a phone app.

Comment: @BladeCoder  Can you provide any link to create my own executor with bigger thread pool as i need to update the result on UI thread so have to go with async task.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not as parallel as you may think.

`execute` method executes an AsyncTask on `SERIAL_EXECUTOR`, which runs task only after the previous is finished.

`executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, ...)` runs it on `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` which has following restrictions:

`CORE_POOL_SIZE = Math.max(2, Math.min(CPU_COUNT - 1, 4));`

`MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;`

That means that you have maximum CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1 tasks executed at the same time.

I really doubt you hit some limit of threads, because there are only couple of them. So your problem is probably in the way you are doing those async tasks. I assume that at some point they are blocking all the threads available for execution and you can't run them anymore.

**4 Suggestions:**

1) Don't use AsyncTask, just run your task on some ExecutorService on the thread pool with amount of threads needed.

2) Revise your ClientTask to not execute it too long.

3) If you still want to use AsyncTask, try to pass different Executor to executeOnExecutor method.

4) You definitely don't need and actually can't run 255 fully parallel tasks on a phone

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:**
Using AsyncTask in android is strongly discouraged.
Especially if there is no need for callbacks to the Main UI thread.

What you should do is implement a thread pool and execute your code with it.
A simple example can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html).

**Long version:**
Max threads available for execution simultaneously varies for different android devices due to multiple variable (such as OS version, processor etc. ).
Further more, if you execute all of your threads simultaneously you essentially force each thread to take time slice from your processor's clock and you end up choking it, so that you do in fact perform a lot of tasks but they all happen very, very slowly.
The correct way would be to create a thread pool and define the maximum amount of threads to run simultaneously so this would not happen.

In either case, AsyncTask is not the recommended way for most use cases.

Good luck =).

Answer (score 0):

If your tasks execute in a limited time, then you don't need a bigger thread pool. Actually the maximum number of concurrent threads in the default `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` on your device is probably limited to 9 (around twice the number of physical CPU cores). That's because increasing concurrency stops improving speed when the CPU, the network or anything else becomes a bottleneck. So the `AsyncTask`s that are not actively running are waiting in a queue and the maximum queue size of `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` is around 128.

The problem is that you try to schedule more than 128 jobs at once and when all threads are busy and the queue becomes full the next `AsyncTask`s are discarded.

So I would recommend that instead, you run all your network requests in sequence in a single `AsyncTask` and batch the results in a list, or if you want some parallelism you can split the job in 2 (0 to 127 and 128 to 255 for example) and run 2 `AsyncTask`s. You get the idea.

You may also use other APIs like RxJava to ease splitting the work in groups and have better control of the execution.